# Is household disposable income a real or a nominal value?

Tags: income, household, turkey

I downloaded `Quintiles/Deciles ordered by household disposable income (Turkey, Urban, Rural))` data from [Turkish Statistics Institue](http://www.turkstat.gov.tr/VeriBilgi.do?alt_id=24). I have looked at the provided data, but it doesn't indicate if the values are in real terms or nominal terms. What is the default for such data? Should I accept it as real disposable income?

Answer (score 1):

Nominal. I'm making a logical leap to say so, but I'm near certain in my answer.

The number for "regular employee" jumped from 9069 to 13707 4 years later. When looking at numbers in the US, the Real number is nearly flat over decades, rising a percent or two in a good year, 10% over one decade in good times. This average income number has jumped 50% in 4 years. I don't know of anything phenomenon that could have done this on a real basis. But 10.7% inflation over that time, there you are. 
By the way, you asked for the default for this data. It can go either way. It's usually stated on the document.

Welcome to SE, yasar!